# c program, pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm making a program that takes a three-digit integer and splits it into two integers. `224` would become `220` and `4`. `114` would become `110` and `4`.

Basically, you do it with modulos. I wrote what I think should work and the compiler keeps saying that there is a missing parenthesis before the `&big` but any changes just make more errors happen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void split_num(int complete, int *big, int *little){
     *little = complete%10;
     *big  = complete - *little;
     return;
}


int main()
{
    int complete, big, little;

    printf("Give an integer to split: \n");
    scanf("%d", &complete);

    void split_num(complete, &big, &little);
    printf("Num split into 2 is : %d and %d", big, little);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you don't want the word `void` before `split_num` when you call it in `main`. see what happens if you remove that

Comment: interested on the fix of this... still learning pointers my self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the "void" in your call to split_num(). It's only used in the function declaration (to signify that it does not return a value), not in actual invocations of it.

Answer (score 0):

The line (in main())

```
void split_num(complete, &big, &little);
```

should read

```
split_num(complete, &big, &little);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the void in the line "void split_num".  You don't specify return values (void) when just calling a method.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the following line:

```
void split_num( complete, &big, &little );
```

Remove the void return type and invoke the function like so:

```
split_num( complete, &big, &little );
```

The return; statement in the split_num( ... ) function is also unnecessary.

Comment: can you give me an example of when a function would not be "void" and would need to return a number? thanks for telling me to remove the void i'm so happy it works!

Comment: @Arthur What you are referring to is the function return type. When a function has a void return type it does not return anything. An example of a function that returns an integer would be int main() which returns zero if your C program executes successfully otherwise non-zero.