# Determine Palindrome - How does operator * work?

Tags: c, pointers, palindrome

This program is supposed to take in a three digit number and change it into its palindrome. `123` would become `321`.

The logic is correct, and the program compiles correctly. :) However, the logic of these does not come easily.

My prof explains things with "stack diagrams" and I find them to be helpful. I created this program based off another program because I noticed the similarities between this and a [different program I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855438/c-program-pointers), but how does the pointing work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_number(int in_val, int *out_val) {
    int ones, tens, hundreds;

    ones = in_val % 10;
    tens = (in_val % 100 - ones) / 10;
    hundreds = (in_val - (ones + tens)) / 100;

    *out_val = (ones * 100) + (tens * 10) + hundreds;
}

int main() {
    int in_val;
    int out_val;

    printf("Give a three digit num to reverse: \n");
    scanf("%d", &in_val);

    reverse_number(in_val, &out_val);
    printf("New number is: %d \n", out_val);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, I am now beginning to understand how to write programs based on a kind of template with these pointers, and I understand very basically what the star inside a parameter means (declared as a pointer variable).

For example, I know that `m = &q;` gives variable `m` the address of another variable `q` and I know that `m = *g;` would mean that the value at the address `g` would go into `m` but I am really unfamiliar with how these work in the context of a function and a main file.

If someone could lay out the fundamental logic of how it would work (in this program) that would be awesome. As a math major, I can understand the operations of the math and stuff but the pointers have me not confused but it just seems to me that there are ways to do it without needing to deal with the address of a variable, etc.

Comment: Oh jeez, between editing this question and editing the program in the compiler the program compiles. My bad. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Many data structures such as Linked Lists and Trees cannot be created without the use of pointers. Pointers are confusing - but they are not useless.

Comment: Edit your question to ask how it works : )

Comment: @Arthur Well the idea behind stack overflow is to provide collective knowledge. I would leave it here because someone down the line may find it in a search and it prove useful to them. Another option would be to see if you can find why it didn't compile, and post your solution as an answer.

Comment: What system/compiler do you use? With Linux/gcc it compiles and runs ok.

Comment: Sorry I can't remember what wasn't working, I think perhaps it was because I left the ampersand out of the called function in the main file. Between editing my question and fooling with the code in Terminal, I must have corrected it (I'm using a Linux box/gcc through my school's cs server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you understood `&` and `*` operators perfectly, the rest is very very simple.

Let's say you have:

```
int q;
int *m;
m = &q;
```

Then if you say:

```
int *m2;
m2 = m;
```

`m2` will contain the same value as `m`, that is, it will have the address of `q`. Therefore, `*m` and `*m2` will give you the same value (which is the value of `q`) (you *do* understand that `*` is the inverse operator of `&` right? So `*(&q) = q` and `&(*m) = m` (in the later case, `m` needs to be a pointer for `*` to be applicable.))

So, how does this work with functions? Simple! When you pass arguments to functions, you pass them by value. When you pass by pointer, you are actually passing by value, the pointer of the variable.

So let's examine your function call in detail:

```
reverse_number(in_orig, &out_orig);
```

I renamed your `in_val` and `out_val` in the main to `in_orig` and `out_orig` so it won't get mixed with those of `reverse_number`.

Now, `&out_orig` is the address of `out_orig`. When passed as arguments, this gets copied into `out_val` argument of `reverse_number`. This is exactly like writing:

```
int *out_val = &out_orig;
```

Now, if you had the above line in your `main`, you could just write `*out_val = something;` and it would change `out_orig`, right? Well, since you have the address of `out_orig` in `out_val`, then who cares if `*out_val` is being set in `main` or `reverse_number`?

So you see? When you have a pointer, you can just copy it around, whether by copying it to another variable or passing it as argument of a function (which is basically the same thing), you can still access the same variable it is pointing to. After all, all the copies have the same value: address of `out_orig`. Now if you want to access it in a function or in `main`, it doesn't really matter.

**Edit**: `*` in pointer definition

`*` can be used to define a pointer too and this has nothing to do with the previous usage of `*` as an operator that gets the value of an address.

This is just definition, so you have to learn it:

If you have a value of type `type` (for example `int`), then the address of that variable (using `operator &`) has type `type *` (in this example `int *`). Since a pointer takes that address, the type of the pointer is `type *`.

On the contrary, if a pointer has type `type *` (for example `int *`), then getting the value where the pointer points to (using `operator *`) has type `type` (in this example `int`).

In summary, you can say something like this:

```
operator &, adds one * to the type of the variable
operator *, removes one * from the type of the expression
```

So let's see some examples:

```
int x;
x has type int
&x has type int *

float *y;
y has type float *
&y has type float **
*y has type float

struct Data ***d;
d has type struct Data ***
&d has type struct Data ****
*d has type struct Data **
*(*d) has type struct Data *
*(*(*d)) has type struct Data
```

If you noticed, I said that `&` adds one `*` to the type of *variable*, but `*` removes one `*` from the type of *expression*. Why is that? Because `&` gives the address of a variable. Of course, because nothing else has an address. For example `a+b` (possibly) doesn't have any address in the memory, and if it does, it's just temporary and useless.

`operator *` however, works on addresses. No matter how you compute the address, `operator *` works on it. Examples:

```
*(0x12345678) -> Note that even if the compiler let's you do this,
                 your program will most likely crash

*d -> like we saw before

*(d+4) -> This is the same as writing d[4]
          And now you know why arrays and pointers are treated as one
```

In case of a dynamic 2d array:

```
*(*(d+4)+6) -> This is the same as writing d[4][6]
```

Comment: when you write "int *m;" in the first few lines, this means that m is declared as a pointer, and this means that it is an address? EDIT: It's just a little confusing. Star means give a value at an address, ampersand means give address of a value, but when you want to declare a variable as being a pointer (an address) you write "int *p" or "float *k". Similarly, when you are writing integer parameters in a function, you can write void something(int *u, int *y) and these parameters are addresses rather than values AT an address. It just seems like star means two slightly different things

Comment: `*` is used with two meanings. One, like you said "value at an address" (Side note: `&` is not address of a value, but is address of a **variable**). Completely irrelevant to _computing the value at an address_, `*` is used to defined pointers. Let me edit my answer and then you read it.

Comment: Thank you Shahbaz I never properly expressed my appreciation at your helping me understand these fundamentals.

Answer (score 5):

When I run it, it compiles, and even works. See: http://ideone.com/RHWwI

So it must be how you're compiling it. What is your compiler error?

Comment: yeah its pretty good but I'm getting an awful lot of runtime errors for things that compile fine on the terminal with high level restrictions. any idea whats up?